# Create popup with alert in AngularJS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on a project and want to have an alert box pop up when the user clicks on the input section. However, I am having issues. Any suggestions?

My html/AngularJS code:

```
<li ng-click="showCustomerList()" class="clickable">
    <label>Customer Info</label>
    <input readonly = "readonly" ng-class = "{editing: ShowCustomerList.isOpen()}" placeholder = "text" value = "{{getCustomerName}}"/>
</li>
```

My JavaScript/AngularJS code:

```
$scope.showCustomerList = function () {
    alert("This is the popup!");
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing the [***ng-app***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive or putting it inside the head tag. Try putting it inside the **html** tag or the **body** tag.

HTML :

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div  ng-controller="MyController">   
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="alertMe()"  class="clickable">Click me</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

myjs.js

```
var myModule = angular.module("TestApp", []);
myModule.controller("MyController", function($scope){
    $scope.alertMe = function(){
        alert("Hello Everyone");
    };
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/djrGA/)

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine.
Take a look **[`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/PqL9W/)**.

Comment: This looks like it works in JSFiddle, but for some reason I can't get it to run in visual studio correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with VS.

Comment: Okay, I also did this in other text editors and it gives the same result: Customer Info {{getCustomerName}}

Comment: You should post the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an ng-click directive to an anchor element:

```
<input readonly="readonly" ng-class="{editing: ShowCustomerList.isOpen()}" placeholder="text" value="{{getCustomerName}}"/>

<a href="" ng-click="showCustomerList()">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: For some reason this still doesn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks!